# How do I fetch data from an unknown # of urls using Javascript/Promises/Fetch/Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I am struggling to get my head around async/promises using Javascript.

This issue is: I have an unknown number of pages to fetch. This only becomes apparent when there is no data returned when attempted.

In summary:

There is a defined base url (postedUrl)

The 'page' number parameter increments by 1 every time a fetch has been completed (and contains data)

Using axios (or what ever) to fetch the page and store the data in a global array - accessible later on

The issue I am having is, being able to successfully run the fetch an unknown amount of times (till there is no more data returned).

Note: The page number is not supposed to be used in the do/while loop. I could not get it to correctly alter isWorking to 0, and stop itself. So I used a temp solution so I could test out the code.

Can anyone advise the best way to do this?

```
const getHostname = (url) => {
    return new URL(url).hostname;
}

let isWorking = 1;
let postedUrl = "https://example.com/"
let parsedUrl = getHostname(postedUrl)
let page_number = 110;

let total_products = 0;

let productList = [];


async function fetchData() {

    axios.get(postedUrl,
        {
            params: {
                page: page_number
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.length == 0) {
                isWorking = 0;
                alert("is triggering");

            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);

        });


    console.log(isWorking);
    page_number++;

}


async function startWork() {
    do {
        await fetchData();
        console.log(isWorking);
    } while (page_number < 115)
}

startWork();
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if a request returns an error? Try again, throw an error or simply continue?

Comment: @InSync if a request contains no data, then stop fetching anymore urls as its come to an end in terms of available data

Answer (score 0):

Recursion could be the answer here. Just try

```
async function startWork() {
    await fetchData()
    if(isWorking) startWork()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are independent of each other, you can get all of them at the same time using [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), which returns a `Promise` that fulfills when all  `Promise`s passed to it has settled:

```js
const pagesToFetch = [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115];
// or Array.from(Array(115 - 110 + 1).keys(), e => e + 110);

const productList = await Promise.allSettled(
  pagesToFetch.map(page => axios.get(/* your url/params/etc. here  */))
);
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const url = 'https://picsum.photos';
const sizesToFetch = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];

let responses;

(async function() {
  responses = await Promise.allSettled(
    sizesToFetch.map(page => {
      return fetch(`${url}/${page}`);
    })
  );
  console.log(responses);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```